# Die wohl dickste Lüge lautete, dass die Person der Star einer Rockband sei

Tags: sentence-structure

I read this sentence in a book:

> Die wohl dickste Lüge lautete, dass die Person der Star einer Rockband sei.

However, I don't understand the construction of this sentence. Why not the word order be to:

> Wohl lautete die dickste Lüge, dass die Person der Star einer Rockband sei.

*Wohl* is an adverb, and the verb should be at position 2?

Comment: Adverbs can also modify adjectives …

Comment: "Wohl" here means "probably" and is an adverb for "dickste". "The probably fattest lie was..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two sentences are both correct, but they have slightly different meanings.

> Die wohl dickste Lüge lautete, dass die Person der Star einer Rockband sei.
>   The lie, that probably is the biggest, says, that the person is the star of a rock band.

The phrase *»die wohl dickste Lüge«* is one part of speech. It is a *Nominalgruppe* or *Nominalphrase* (*nominal phrase*), and this hole phrase is the subject of the sentence, so this group occupies only one position in the sentence (position 1), and therefore the verb (*»lautete«*) is where it has to be: on position 2.

In this phrase the adverb *wohl* (*probably*) modifies the adjective *dickste* (*biggest*). This adverb is not bound to the verb!

---

> Wohl lautete die dickste Lüge, dass die Person der Star einer Rockband sei.
>   The biggest lie says probably, that the person is the star of a rock band.

Here the word *»wohl«* on its own is a part of speech that occupies position 1. It is an adverb that modifies a verb (which is at position 2).

Comment: While the meaning becomes clear, a possibly better translation is "The probably biggest lie was the person being a star of a rockband".

Comment: It might be worth adding that the second construction is usually chosen if we want to create a contrast: wohl... aber...

Comment: Die Lüge wird in Beispiel 2 zum Wohllaut. "Gut klang die dickste Lüge, ..."

Answer (score 1):

Wohl is an adverb to dickste in the sense of vermutlich, vermeintlich.